# why setOnInfoListener not supported for VideoView?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am creating an application in which I am using `VideoView` to stream  video from URL Source. The video is taking some time to buffer and play so I set `onPrepareListener` to `VideoView` and I display `Progress Dialogue` while it buffers and remove it when the playing starts. But again after sometime it starts buffering.I want to show `Progress Dialogue` again. I had earlier used `OInfoListener` with `MediaPlayer` to listen to buffering,but with `VideoView` I am not able to set `OInfoListener`. I want to know is it possible to `setOnInfoListener` with 'VideoView`. If not then how to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener l) {
    super.setOnCompletionListener(l);
}

@Override
public void setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener l) {
    super.setOnErrorListener(l);
}

@Override
public void setOnPreparedListener(OnPreparedListener l) {
    super.setOnPreparedListener(l);
}
```

these are the listeners available for videoview

Comment: why not `setOnInfoListener()`

Comment: if u import mediaplayer u can use it my friend ...for videoview the above listener can be used

Comment: But I saw the code of VideoView it is using MediaPlayer only to play the Video. Then why not we can use OnInfoListener ?